# Notation to distinguish "indifference" and "drawn from"

Tags: probability, notation, order-theory

I am writing a paper in which I need to denote indifference (with respect to some preference ordering) as well as sampling from a distribution.

Unfortunately, both are typically represented using the $\sim$ symbol; $x\sim y$ to denote indifference between $x$ and $y$, and $\theta \sim f_\Theta$ to denote that $\theta$ is a sample drawn from the distribution $f_\Theta$.

What's the best way to reconcile this conflict? Should I just rely on context?

Comment: I think it's probably fine relying on context.  If you really wanted, you could use two different fonts for the tilde and define what each font tilde means in the beginning of the paper.